# Align Bootstrap Carousel Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using a Bootstrap carousel to display images and their respective captions. The image can be portrait, landscape.

I'm able to correctly display landscape images in the carousel with their caption below. In case of Portrait images I'm trying to align the centre image to the right so that it does not overlap with the caption. I changed the CSS property in file **bootstrap.min.css** but it's not working.

**CSS code**...

```
 .carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  align: right;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
```

Any idea how to align Portrait image to the right without affecting the other 2 images?

The obj parameter is contains the image src, caption details. The values are being returned by an ajax function being called to the back-end service.

HTML Code..

```
     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <div id="carouselObject">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-pause="true" data-interval="5000000">    <!--data-interval= 5000 seconds-->  
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="carouselinner">

                </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#/carousel-example-generic" role="button">               <!--data-slide="prev"-->
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" onclick="loadPrevSlide()" id="leftcarouselbutton"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#/carousel-example-generic" role="button">              <!--data-slide="next"-->
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" onclick="loadNextSlide()" id="rightcarouselbutton"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: could you make a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

i have created code pen for similar carousel slider. have a look at once it may helpful for you.

```
   <head> <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="carosel-example">
   <div id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
     <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
     <img   alt="900x500" src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>First slide </h3>
        <p> ContentContentContentContentContentContent</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img   alt="900x500" src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second slide</h3>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img    src="http://a.static.trunity.net/files/299501_299600/299598/vertical-farming-chris-jacobs.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third slide</h3>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

///// CSS code goes here

```
  .carousel-caption {
   color: #000;
  }.carosel-example, .new-caption-area {
width: 600px;
margin: auto;
color: #000;
 }
```

////////////// JS CODE

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('.carousel').carousel();
var caption = $('div.item:nth-child(1) .carousel-caption');
$('.new-caption-area').html(caption.html());
caption.css('display', 'none');

$(".carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
    var caption = $('div.item:nth-child(' + ($(evt.relatedTarget).index() + 1) + ') .carousel-caption');
    $('.new-caption-area').html(caption.html());
    caption.css('display', 'none');
});
});
```

http://codepen.io/srinivasr/pen/EPdxKG

Comment: Each of the 3 squares in my carousel is 300x300. I want only the centre image(portrait image) to be aligned in the right side of the 300x300 square without changing the alignment of other images..So the caption of middle image will be on the left side of 300x300 square and it's image on the right side..Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code. Please take a look.